# Invariant Violation: React error #130

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So i was currently trying to render the code for a custom sidebar found in  the site: [How to build a custom sidebar in React](https://ashiknesin.com/blog/build-custom-sidebar-component-react/)
. But i am getting the error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
>   Check the render method of `TheSidebar`

I cannot comprehend what is wrong with it, but still, i am new to React. Running it on Node. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const { IndexLink, Link } = require('react-router');
// import './Sidebar.scss'
const classNames = require('classnames');




class TheSidebar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showMenu: false
        }
        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this), true);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this), true);
    }
    toggleMenu() {
        this.setState({ showMenu: !this.state.showMenu })
    }
    handleClickOutside(event) {
        const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

        if ((!domNode || !domNode.contains(event.target))) {
            this.setState({
                showMenu: false
            });
        }
    }

    render() {

        const showMenu = this.state.showMenu;
        const sidebarClass = classNames({
            'sidebar': true,
            'sidebar-menu-expanded': showMenu,
            'sidebar-menu-collapsed': !showMenu
        });

        const elementsClass = classNames({
            'expanded-element': true,
            'is-hidden': !showMenu,
        });



    return (
      <nav className={sidebarClass}>
        <img
          className="menuIcon"
          // src={}
          onClick={this.toggleMenu}
        />
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link className="expandable" to="/setting" title="Setting">
              <img
                src={'https://png.icons8.com/setting/ffffff'}
                alt=""
              />
              <span className={elementsClass}>Setting</span>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

        );
    }
}


module.exports = TheSidebar;
```

The sidebar is then injected into an App file along with a header and then rendered. The app file and render file are as follows:

```
const React = require('react');
const Header = require('./Header.jsx');
const TheSidebar = require('./Sidebar.jsx');

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <head>
                    <title>TESTING</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <TheSidebar />
                    </div>
                </body>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
module.exports = App;
```

And the rendering:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "../views"));
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
app.engine('jsx', createEngine());
app.get("/testing", function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/App.jsx');
});
```

Comment: Make sure the `Link` component from react-router is properly imported.

Comment: @Sulthan How can i make sure that it is properly imported?

Comment: @Sulthan, as it seems from a console.log, the Link is not properly imported and i don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link and IndexLink are exported as fields within a default object export, so if you're using "require" then first get the default export:

```
const ReactRouter = require('react-router')
```

And then pick out individual fields:

```
const IndexLink = ReactRouter.IndexLink
const Link = ReactRouter.Link
```

EDIT: If your react-router version is  >= 4.0, then Index is longer inside it. Its in react-router-dom. And IndexLink is no longer available. You should probably revert to 3.x to run this example code

Comment: Your point is good. But i just tried it, and the error is still persisting.

Comment: have the version 4.2, so i guess i need to revert it for all the time's sake i put into this :/ But i am confused how can i revert?

Comment: I mean, i know i can install earlier versions, but will the require() method make use of the old version, so the app will work?

Comment: Just remove the 4.x version from your package.json, i.e in your package.json change react-router to some 3.x version, like 3.0.5  for instance and run 'npm install' again and your require statement will pick it up.

Comment: I did not have to uninstall 4.x at all, because in the moment i installed a 3.x.x version, it rendered. Thank you very much Doug, that helped me alot. Now on to the stylesheet hell for me :-P

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the IndexLink and Link component correctly. Check out named imports in ES6.

You should import them like this.

```
import { IndexLink, Link } from 'react-router'
```

Comment: I cannot do that because i am running it on node.js . I actually should add that to my post, my bad.

Comment: Can you show how you are using this component in your app? Because I just copied this same code in my app and it seems to be working fine.